# how to create sublime text macro with selected line of code?

Tags: macros, sublimetext2

I'm trying to do an other sublime text macro.

I will simplify what i would like :
I select a line of code, press the macro key and the macro will add 1 line of text above and 2 more below the selected line.

Ex:

```
My line of code
```

I select the line, press macro key and the code may be like :

```
echo('init');
My line of code
echo('After line');
echo('again after');
```

I already try the record macro tools but it's not working for the text selected and for go to the line after the selected.

I know how to use key binding it's just for the macro file...

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a macro for that, you can directly create a keybinding (obviously you can also move it to a macro):

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+a"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "echo('init');\n$SELECTION\necho('After line');\necho('again after');"
    },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

Aside: if you only write you macros to trigger them from keybindings you might be interested in the [ChainOfCommand](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) package.